# Is creating page files on separate HDDs a good thing or unnecessary with lots of RAM on Win7x64?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory

I have set the page file to custom using the recommended mbs and noticed on my two other hdds that they were blank and was wondering if it would be necessary to set up page files on those hdds. I have os on c:/ and two other hdd f:/& s:/ all are 1tb 7200rpm sataIII disks. I have 16gb of ram btw.

Comment: A single page file is sufficient. Maybe someone will take the time to explain why having a page file is good, even with that much RAM.

Comment: Thanks guys think I'll just set it to recommended and let it go at that I reall don't do much 'page filing'.

Answer (score 3):

Necessary, no.

However, by spreading your pagefile across multiple drives you will gain a performance increase.  This is due to the fact that Windows will use the pagefile on the disk that is least active.  Depending on your usage, you *may* see a performance increase, but only if you found yourself paging a lot before.

Comment: this is somewhat similar to RAID 0 because the disk load is balanced between drives

Answer (score 1):

With 16G of ram you do not nessisarily need huge paging files, depending entirely on what your usage is. You could potentially get away with a small one of 1/2-1G which will keep most programs from freaking out.  If your doing really huge databases multiple huge pictures and stuff like that you probably would know if you need more.

Putting the paging file on **a seperate disk from where the data will come from that is being paged** is "better" because one disk can be doing I/O while the other is also.  Say your editing gig sized tiff files in a photo program , and you get some paging, it would be better if the paging is on a different disk than the tiff data files, so from-->to can occur without IwhileO (simeltanious input output) from a Hard drive storage unit.
If somehow it is the programs that are paging, then your better off with the paging file on a disk that the programs are not on.
In the situation with 16g and not paging a lot of program data, and only paging out some kernel stuff that is not going to be used for some time, the paging would be fine being on the system disk or the C disk. Asumption here is if you load in huge data files from your data type disks , while they are reading in, paging out can occur simeltanious on the other disk.

In the situation with a load of ram, and zero need to ever page large data out, because you just do not ever do that, then your only paging some kernel stuff and possibly paging some program data, and the paging would be best on the data disk.

2 Paging files on different disks the system is supposed to make the best use of both of them as would be best in the situation (I have never actually seen this) , so a person could make paging files on all the disks (even minor sized paging) and the system should be using the best one.

**Caveats:** Having paging only in the default System disk, of the windows default size is most safe, if that disk is not operational , then neither is the system doing the paging :-)
 Putting it on only the data disks means you have to pay attention to the existance of it being there, if you pull it, or format it or whatever, and you only had the one, then you have none.   So messing with it, is fun and advantageous in some situations, but an unnessiary awareness would be important when you change it.

Whole data dumps of the ram require there to be a 1-1 or more paging size, little dumps only need some paging to exist.

So basically there are a whole lot of ways you can do it, including having none and having some programs (including games) fail with weird errors.  It is just a matter of "where did you want to go today"  Depending (again) on what you want to do. A 1/2g on your system disk C and a 1 gig one on on the least used "other" disk would probably do the job fine with 16g of ram.  That is what I had and knowing and observing How the ram was used and paging was used, it was ok for me. It may not work for others.  If your actually using way beyond the physical ram, then it does not hurt anything to have paging files on each of the disks.

glossary:  Disk not partition in this case, the key being to make use of more hardware items, more drive units, not overdoing things in ways that just make it more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I tried spreading the pagefilesys over two other hard drives and no page on my ssd and it opened up 25 gigs of space on the ssd. all seems well letting windows determine the size on the other two.

Answer (score -1):

Creating unnecessary page files will only waste your disk space :) 
When creating virtual RAM using page file, you will get a recommended space there. You can use the recommended space only. Windows determines how much space you need from your hard disk.

Or you can set little bit higher. But don't add too much space on your hard disk as page file. And your RAM is enough. So, do not use too much space as page file. Just use the recommended size by the Windows.

And I think it's better to share C drive for virtual memory (if there is enough space)

If you need any further help you can go here - [Change Virtual Size Memory](http://www.markspcsolution.com/2013/03/change-virtual-memory.html).

Hope this will help. Thanks.